# Extracting the gradient during PyTorch fit functions

Tags: pytorch, parameters, gradient, loss

I am trying to train a neural network until the L2-norm of its gradient is within 10e-3 of 0; therefore, my code includes defining the parameters and gradients that are computed during the fit process. I keep hitting snags that make me think I am not getting at the parameters or gradient correctly.

Here is my code:

```
def get_theta(self):
    theta = self.parameters().detach().cpu
    return theta

def J_loss(self, xb, yb):
    #forward returns x so here it will return x on GPU
    #return cross_entropy result of xb and yb on GPU
    return F.cross_entropy(self.forward(xb.to(device)), yb.to(device))

def fit(self, loader, epochs = 1999):
    norm2Gradient = 1
    while norm2Gradient >10e-3 and epochs <2000:
        #grad = []
        for _, batch in enumerate(loader):
            x, y = batch['x'], batch['y']
            #computes f.cross_entropy loss of (xb,yb) on GPU 
            loss = self.J_loss(x,y) 
            #print("loss:", loss)
            #computes new gradients
            grad = loss.backward()
            #print("grad:",grad)
            print("grad?",grad)
            #takes one step along new gradients to decrease the loss; updates parameters 
            self.optimizer.step()  
            #captures new parameters
            theta = self.parameters()
            print("theta:",theta)
            #collects gradient along new parameters
            for param in theta:
                grad.append(param.grad)
            #computes gradient norm
            norm2Gradient = torch.linalg.norm(grad)
            sumNorm2Gradient += norm2Gradient.detach().cpu
            #clears out old gradients  
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    return sumNorm2Gradient
```

The current error message, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'" occurs at the line:

```
grad.append(param.grad)
```

Additionally, the print out of the variable "grad" is "None". I have combed through documentation trying to figure out what each line is doing in the code and how to extract the gradient and parameters. How do I correctly get at the gradient?

Comment: Is it possible that you're getting `None` because you're not calculating your gradient in the first place? Check out [requires_grad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.requires_grad.html). If you're [not telling autograd to keep track of it, then it will return None](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/none-type-return-while-trying-to-find-gradient-of-models-parameters/160786/2?u=brock_brown).
If that's not the case, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have been looking into this idea. I am using DataLoader whose default setting is requires_grad = False and have been trying to figure out a work-around. I am currently in a rabbit hole about leaf vs. non-leaf tensors.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `grad` the following way in your code:

```
        grad = loss.backward()
```

You are getting this error because [`torch.Tensor.backward`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/autograd.html#backward) returns precisely `None`.

Comment: Might you have a tip on how to attain the gradient?

Comment: I think the solution may lie within this source https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autograd_tutorial.html and figuring out how to get at "w" and "b" when using DataLoader. Will share what I find when I do.

Comment: Why not use [`torch.autograd.grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.grad.html)?

Comment: when i use torch.autograd.grad, i get this error messege:  UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the .grad field to be populated for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here

```py
for _, batch in enumerate(loader):
    ...
    grad = loss.backward()
    ...
    for param in theta:
        grad.append(param.grad)
    ...
```

`backward` does not return a value. When you run `grad = loss.backward()`, you are assigning `grad = None`. Later, you attempt to append values to `None` via `grad.append(param.grad)`, hence the error.

Comment: Suggestion on attaining the gradient of the loss function?

Comment: I think the solution may lie within this source https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autograd_tutorial.html and figuring out how to get at "w" and "b" when using DataLoader. Will share what I find when I do.

Comment: When you call `backward`, gradients are backpropped to your leaf tensors. There isn't a single gradient of the loss function. There is a gradient tensor for each parameter in the model.

Comment: You should review pytorch documentation. There is a gradient tensor for each parameter. The shape of each gradient tensor matches the corresponding weight tensor. There is not a single "vector of gradients". Gradients are only computed for leaf tensors, like model parameters. Gradients are not computed for intermediate values like activations.

Comment: In the PyTorch documentation, I keep coming across: leaf vs. non-leaf tensors. 

Let N = # nodes in NN. Let n = # features in one input x. Therefore, the number of weights = N x n. Let W be in R^(N x n) represent a weights matrix. Let G be in R^(N x n) represent a gradient matrix -- partials of cost w.r.t. weights.

Would a "leaf tensors" be a tensor associated w the first layer of NN (and, therefore, the last layer of back propagation)? For example, is the first row of matrix G defined above a "leaf tensor" and the other rows of G "non-leaf" tensors?